# Concatenating subsets of blast hits according to their position to get complete hits

Tags: python, xml, biopython, blast

I am using biopython to do something similar to this,
[Sort rps-blast results by position of the hit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16070195/sort-rps-blast-results-by-position-of-the-hit) but want to join or concatenate local hits to have  contiguous stretch of queries and subject hits.

My code:

```
for record in records:
   for alignment in record.alignments:
                hits = sorted((hsp.query_start, hsp.query_end, hsp.sbjct_start, hsp.sbjct_end, alignment.title, hsp.query, hsp.sbjct)\
                               for hsp in alignment.hsps)
                for q_start, q_end, sb_start, sb_end, title, query, sbjct in hits:
                      print title
                      print 'The query starts from position: ' + str(q_start)
                      print 'The query ends at position: ' + str(q_end)
                      print 'The hit starts at position: ' + str(sb_start)
                      print 'The hit ends at position: ' + str(sb_end)
                      print 'The  query is: ' + query
                      print 'The hit is: ' + sbjct
```

This would give sorted results as so:

```
Species_1
The query starts from position: 1
The query ends at position: 184
The hit starts at position: 1
The hit ends at position: 552
The query is: #######query_seq
The hit is: ######### hit_seq
Species_1
The query starts from position: 390
The query ends at position: 510
The hit starts at position: 549
The hit ends at position: 911
The query is: #######query_seq
The hit is: ######### hit_seq
Species_1
The query starts from position: 492
The query ends at position: 787
The hit starts at position: 889
The hit ends at position: 1776
The query is: #######query_seq
The hit is: ######### hit_seq
```

This is all fine but I want go the next logical step and that is to concatenate all the three sub_queries and sub-hits shown here (the number of hits do vary) to get complete query and subject sequences. What could be the way forward?

Comment: Just to make sure: Can't you remove the overlapped portion of the sequences and concatenate one after another? Sorry, man! I am not sure about what you are trying to do.

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun, thanks for the observation. Yes, overlapping hits is another layer of complexity, but essentially what I want to get is a sequence (non-overlapping) of both the query and the hit -- in this case I want the program get the first portion of query [1:184]+ second portion of query[390:510]+third portion of query[492:787]. The same thing to subject hits. The overlap issue with the second and the third need be addressed so thanks for a note and hope that clears some of the confusions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okk, so I am giving you a sample solution. Hope, it will help!

You can create an empty variable outside of the loop and concatenate the query string to that variable. Here is an edit on your given code:

```
expected_query_seq = ""
for record in records:
   for alignment in record.alignments:
                hits = sorted((hsp.query_start, hsp.query_end, hsp.sbjct_start, hsp.sbjct_end, alignment.title, hsp.query, hsp.sbjct)\
                               for hsp in alignment.hsps)
                for q_start, q_end, sb_start, sb_end, title, query, sbjct in hits:
                      print title
                      print 'The query starts from position: ' + str(q_start)
                      print 'The query ends at position: ' + str(q_end)
                      print 'The hit starts at position: ' + str(sb_start)
                      print 'The hit ends at position: ' + str(sb_end)
                      print 'The  query is: ' + query
                      print 'The hit is: ' + sbjct

                      expected_query_seq += str(query[q_start:q_end])
print expected_query_seq
```

Comment: Thanks for that. It's a big starting point so hope to carry it further. The minor quiver is that with string slicing as [q_start:q_end] the program concatenate everything within that slice portion. You'd notice in my example the first portion of query starts at 1:184, then there is a jump of 206 seq to the second portion which starts at 390:510, etc. With [q_start:q_end] that means slicing everything from [1:510] and the program include the 206 seq which are not supposed to be included. Any go around this?